# Create a Report PDF out of a process

Tags: c#, compare

I am comparing two tables. I will get the rows that wasn't found in the other table and count everything that's possible.
This information should be Reported in a file with an good overview.
I read the tables from the files! Like a CSV but they are text files.

My Table class:

```
   class TableModel {

    private string tableName;
    private string[] headers;
    private string[] keys;

    public int HeaderCount { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
    public string TableName { get { return tableName; } set { this.tableName = value; } }
    public string[] Headers { get { return headers; } set { this.headers = value; } }
    public string[] Keys { get { return keys; } set { this.keys = value; } }
}
```

My TableLoader:

```
class TableLoader {


    public TableModel LoadTable(string path) {

        TableModel model = new TableModel();

        FileStream filestream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        using(StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filestream, Encoding.UTF8)){

            string line = "";
            bool isHeader = true;
            int index = 0;
            model.RowCount = File.ReadAllLines(path).Length;
            string[] rows = new string[model.RowCount-1];
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
                if (isHeader) {
                    model.Headers = line.Split(new string[]{"\t"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                    isHeader = false;
                    continue;
                }
                rows[index] = line;
                index++;
            }
            model.HeaderCount = model.Headers.Length;
            model.Keys = rows;
        }
        return model;
    }
}
```

My Compare Class:
Only to give an idea of what I want to do.

```
class Compare {

    //Tables CURRENT | NEW
    TableModel newModel;
    TableModel currentModel;
    string dirName;
    //REPORT.txt
    private static string report;

    //Contents
    HashSet<string> currentContent;
    HashSet<string> newContent;

    //Headers
    HashSet<string> headersNotFoundInC = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<string> headersNotFoundInN = new HashSet<string>();
    private bool headerSequence = false;
    //Rows
    HashSet<string> rowNotFoundInC = new HashSet<string>();
    HashSet<string> rowNotFoundInN = new HashSet<string>();

    //Constructor
    public Compare(TableModel newModel, TableModel currentModel, string dirName) {

        this.newModel = newModel;
        this.currentModel = currentModel;
        this.dirName = dirName;
        StartCompare();
        CreateReportFile();
    }

    //METHODS
    private void CreateReportFile() {
    }
    private void StartCompare() {
    }  

    public void checkHeaders() {
    }
    public void checkRows() {
    }

    public void ShowNotFoundHeaders() {
    }
    public void ShowNotFoundRows() {
    }

    public void CheckHeaderCount() {
    }
    public void CheckRowCount() {
    }

    public void ReportHeaders() {
    }
    public void ReportRows() {
    }

    public void SetTitle(string title) {
    }
}
```

Comment: Please ask a single question: otherwise things will get confused. Also: also talk of tables, but you're doing file i/o: do you want compare files or tables?

Comment: Have you even searched on google for "Create pdf in c#" ?

Comment: I edited my question and yes i search in google